# VueJS 2 server-side rendering with jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2, vue.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to convert an old landing page that has a few jQuery plugins to a Vue app. The reason is, that the landing page is being extended and will become a web app.

Using https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/ as a template. Main reason is that it does server side rendering.

Problem is the error:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (__vue_ssr_bundle__:3398:2408)
    at __webpack_require__ (__vue_ssr_bundle__:21:30)
    at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (__vue_ssr_bundle__:1280:126)
    at __webpack_require__ (__vue_ssr_bundle__:21:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (__vue_ssr_bundle__:2099:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (__vue_ssr_bundle__:21:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (__vue_ssr_bundle__:1380:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (__vue_ssr_bundle__:21:30)
    at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (__vue_ssr_bundle__:378:66)
    at __webpack_require__ (__vue_ssr_bundle__:21:30)
```

So far, I've found out that the problem is caused by `window` not being in Node. However, I do not know how to make it available or how I should inject jQuery after the page is server side rendered.

vue-hackernews-2.0 is almost unchanged. The main change I did was adding jQuery to `webpack.client.config.js`.

This is added to `plugins` (found another answer that it should make jQuery available when it's needed in the app):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jquery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

And this is the `LandingView.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="landing-page">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import owl from '../../public/assets/libs/owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4/owl.carousel.min.js'
  import $ from 'jquery';

  export default {
    name: 'landing-view',
    created () {
      console.log('hello world!');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to inject my jQuery plugin on `mounted` event https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#mounted

It also says

> This hook is not called during server-side rendering.

I just assigned the plugin to `window` and then I was able to initiate it.

```
<template>
  <div class="landing-page">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // import $ from 'jquery'; //no need to import it, as it's provided by webpack

  export default {
    name: 'landing-view',
    mounted() {
      // created() is only available in v1

      window.owl = require('../../public/assets/libs/owl.carousel.2.0.0-beta.2.4/owl.carousel.min.js');


      // the rest of my code
      $('.some-carousel').owlCarousel();

    }
  }
</script>
```

---

I am not sure if this is the proper way to solve this. I appreciate any comments on best practices!